# IPFS hash algorithm

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ipfs

### How actually is an IPFS hash (ipfs add) is generated?

I'm looking for step by step operations done on input(*bytes/string*) to get output(*in this case IPFSHash*)

Answer (score 16):

IPFS uses [multihash](https://github.com/multiformats/multihash) where the format is the following:

> **base58(<varint hash function code><varint digest size in bytes><hash function output>)**

The list of hash function codes can be found in [this table](https://github.com/multiformats/multihash/blob/master/hashtable.csv).

Here's some pseudocode of the process using [SHA2-256](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) as the hashing function.

```
sha2-256   size  sha2-256("hello world")
0x12       0x20  0xb94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
```

Concatenating those three items will produce

```
1220b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
```

Which then you encode it to [base58](https://incoherency.co.uk/base58/)

```
QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

---

**Here's an example of how to implement multihash in JavaScript:**

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const bs58 = require('bs58')

const data = 'hello world'
const hashFunction = Buffer.from('12', 'hex') // 0x20

const digest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest()
console.log(digest.toString('hex')) // b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9

const digestSize = Buffer.from(digest.byteLength.toString(16), 'hex')
console.log(digestSize.toString('hex')) // 20

const combined = Buffer.concat([hashFunction, digestSize, digest])
console.log(combined.toString('hex')) // 1220b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9

const multihash = bs58.encode(combined)
console.log(multihash.toString()) // QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

---

**There's a CLI you can use to generate multihashes:**

```
$ go get github.com/multiformats/go-multihash/multihash
$ echo -n "hello world" | multihash -a sha2-256
QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

---

**A file in IPFS is "transformed" into a Unixfs "file", which is a representation of files in a [DAG](https://github.com/ipfs/specs/tree/master/merkledag)**. So when you use `add` to upload a file to IPFS, the data has metadata wrapper which will give you a different result when you multihash it.

For example:

```
$ echo -n "hello world" | ipfs add -Q
Qmf412jQZiuVUtdgnB36FXFX7xg5V6KEbSJ4dpQuhkLyfD
```

---

**Here's an example in Node.js of how to generate the exact same multihash as `ipfs add`:**

```
const Unixfs = require('ipfs-unixfs')
const {DAGNode} = require('ipld-dag-pb')

const data = Buffer.from('hello world', 'ascii')
const unixFs = new Unixfs('file', data)

DAGNode.create(unixFs.marshal(), (err, dagNode) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  console.log(dagNode.toJSON().multihash) // Qmf412jQZiuVUtdgnB36FXFX7xg5V6KEbSJ4dpQuhkLyfD
})
```

---

Hope this helps

Comment: Is it possible to retrive uploaded file's `md5sum` using IPFS or from its IPFS-hash? @Miguel Mota

Comment: @alper you'd have to download the content and then do the md5sum on it. I don't believe it'd be possible to calculate the md5sum from just the ipfs hash

Comment: If a folder has few different files, how will be the main folder's hash is obtained in `ipfs`? If we know the hash of the files from them could we generate the parent folder's hash?